# I have a "sendto() Invalid argument" when i send a second message with my sockets code

Tags: c++, class, sockets

I tried to write a class in C++ for sending sockets to a server and listening for his response.

My code works well but i want to still connected to the server, so i'm writting a class so the object can still have a connection.

#include "client.h"

```
/*
    Simple tcp client
*/
#include <stdio.h>;    //printf
#include <string.h>; //memset
#include <stdlib.h>; //exit(0);
#include <arpa/inet.h>;
#include <sys/socket.h>;

#define SERVER 2;
#define BUFLEN 512    //Max length of buffer
#define PORT 10000    //The port on which to send data

//int sendToServer(__u8 [BUFLEN],__u8 * );

class ClientSocket{
    private:
        struct sockaddr_in si_other;
        int s, i, slen=sizeof(si_other);

        char buf[BUFLEN];

    public:
        void connectTo();
        void die(char *s){
            perror(s);
            exit(1);
        }

        int sendToServer(u_int8_t [BUFLEN],u_int8_t *);
};


 client.cpp

void ClientSocket::connectTo(){
    if ((this->s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)) == -1){
        this->die("socket");
    }

    memset((char *) &si_other, 0, sizeof(this->si_other));
    this->si_other.sin_family = AF_INET;
    this->si_other.sin_port = htons(PORT);

    if (inet_aton("127.0.0.1", &si_other.sin_addr) == 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "inet_aton() failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    if(connect(this->s,(struct sockaddr *) &this->si_other,sizeof(this->si_other)) == -1)
    {
        die("connect()");
    }
}

int ClientSocket::sendToServer(u_int8_t messageBin[BUFLEN],u_int8_t * msgTx){
    char message[BUFLEN];

    for (size_t k = 0; k < BUFLEN; k++) {
        message[k] = (char) messageBin[k];
    }

    //send the message
    if (sendto(this->s, message, strlen(message) , 0 , (struct sockaddr *) &si_other, slen)==-1)
    {
        die("sendto()");
    }

    //receive a reply and print it
    //clear the buffer by filling null, it might have previously received data
    memset(this->buf,'\0', BUFLEN);
    //try to receive some data, this is a blocking call
    if (recvfrom(this->s, this->buf, 512, 0,(struct sockaddr *) &si_other,(socklen_t*) &slen) == -1)
    {
        die("recvfrom()");
    }

    printf("Message recieve by server: ");
    puts(buf);
    printf("\n");

    for (size_t k = 0; k < BUFLEN; k++) {
        msgTx[k] = (u_int8_t) this->buf[k];
    }

    return 1;
}
```

It works well for the first message but I have the error "sendto() Invalid argument" when the second message it send.

Comment: Which part of the shown code makes sure that `message` is 0-terminated, so that `strlen()` does not result in undefined behavior, and which part of the shown code makes sure that `BUFLEN` is at least 512, so that `recv()` doesn't overflow the buffer and corrupt memory?

Comment: Why are you using `sendto()` and `recvfrom()` with TCP? You're connected, so you should be using `send()` and `recv()`.

Comment: I use the good function and it work perfectly, i didn't see until i ask the question. Thks !

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I stop using strlen because i didn't had all the message when i send 0 by socket. I don't understand the second part of your question ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution :

The function sendto and recvfrom are not for TCP connection.

I use send and recv, and it works correctly now.